# oracle apex CSV upload no data found error

Tags: oracle, oracle-apex

I have an apex application which will upload .CSV file

I have 2 users both having same db access rights

One user able to upload .CSV file where second user is getting no data found error.

I m trying with same data .CSV file.

Any thoughts ?

-M Kani

Comment: Are the both users able to access the table ? try a select on the table for the both users

Comment: Those users does not have db login only apex login is granted. They can't directly login to db

Comment: Sorry its allowing to login inside dB. Let me check access

Comment: make sure that both users can select the table

Comment: Is this something because of user role? As we have end user, developer, admin. Do we need to change user role. Please advise

Answer (score 0):

Resolution: removing users uploaded file from www_flow_file_objects$

Issue: user uploaded csv files with incorrect data's. this caused the issue. So removed those csv file data and it worked

Example incorrect data: REF# etc.